# User Registration - MEAN stack - Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

### Intro

I'm currently following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-RfqbZMNtaOXJQiDebNXjVapWPZ) (made in Feb. 2017) by Brad Traversy to try and acquaint myself with the MEAN stack, and I've come across an issue that I'm not able to solve. Using the RESTED Client for Firefox I'm sending a POST request to /register.

Request:

```
{
  "name": "paul",
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "username": "paul",
  "password": "123456"
}
```

### Error

```
Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at _async (/home/paulb/Documents/Projects/mean_auth_app/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:214:46)
    at Object.bcrypt.hash (/home/paulb/Documents/Projects/mean_auth_app/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:220:13)
    at bcrypt.genSalt (/home/paulb/Documents/Projects/mean_auth_app/models/user.js:39:12)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/paulb/Documents/Projects/mean_auth_app/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:153:21)
    at runCallback (timers.js:693:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:664:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:646:5)
```

### addUser Function

```
module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
}
```

### Routing

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  let newUser = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
    if(err){
      res.json({success:false, msg:'Failed to Register User'});
    } else {
      res.json({success:true, msg:'User Registered'});
    }
  });
});
```

### User Schema

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

### "Debugging"

Following the advice left [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240810/iferr-throw-err-error-illegal-arguments-string-undefined) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982964/bcrypt-error-illegal-arguments-string-unidentified), I inserted console.log statements (into the if statement of the addUser function).

```
module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
  console.log(newUser.password);
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(newUser);
        console.log(newUser.password);
        console.log(salt);
      } else {
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(callback);
      }
    });
  });
```

Which returns the following

```
{ _id: 5c329ce56871660e010323bd }
undefined
$2a$10$yrVVaTXDT3zIe5tV6mneH.
```

Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982964/bcrypt-error-illegal-arguments-string-unidentified) suggested that it was due to another user existing in the database with the same username. But the database isn't even being created yet.

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

Despite "connecting" to it:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started on port 3000
Connected to Database: mongodb://localhost:27017/meanauth
```

Code for that here:

```
mongoose.connect(config.database);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log("Connected to Database: "+config.database);
});

mongoose.connection.on('Error', (err) => {
  console.log("Failed Connecting to Database:  "+err);
});
```

Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982858/illegal-arguments-undefined-string) suggested applying  `await` to `salt` and `password`, but I'm not sure how that would be done in this context, or if it would be necessary.

I hope that the information provided above was sufficient.

Comment: I'm going through the same tutorial and ran into something similar. It actually wasn't an issue with the code itself, but with how the request being sent was structured.

I was using Postman and had forgotten to set the request type to `application/json` (it defaulted to text). This meant `body-parser` couldn't parse the body of the request and as such was populating `name`, `email`, and `password` with undefined values.

Have you checked what the RESTFUL client has for a content header type for the request to ensure it is JSON?

Answer (score 1):

it says here in the error, invalid arguments are passed to the bcrypt
and it says undifined string, it could be your password from req doesn't come to the brypt
method for it to genarate the hash thus the error.
so console log and see whether your are getting the 123456 as the password before bcrypt method so that you can make sure the passwors is available for bcrypt to make the hash
I'm pretty sure you will get undefined there..

```
module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){console.log(newUser.password); // try this 
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
}
```

in your model

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema ); //have you done this
```

Comment: Please look at the debugging section

Comment: yeah it says undefined isn't it. so the value it not coming all the way to the bcrypt function

Comment: I have edited the answer try it like that and see whether you are getting 123456 as the password to hash

Comment: have your exported your user model the time of compile

Comment: Just so you know, that's how my code was already structured, with the exception of the console.log statement in your code being before bcrypt.genSalt instead of the if statement. I'm aware that the issue is the variables are undefined, what I don't know is why. That is why I included the console.log statements in the debugging section in the first place. Also, the password is still undefined before the bcrypt.gensalt so I don't see why that's necessary when we already know that it is.

Comment: have your exported your user model

Comment: You'll have to ask that question in code, since i don't know specifically what that means. It is included where it needs to be if that's what you're asking (`const User = require('../models/user');`)

Comment: Yes I have that. The 'user' parameter in mine is capitalized, but either way it doesn't make a difference to the output